# Match a particular word after double quotes - c#,regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match a particular word which is followed by double quotes.
I am using regex **@"\bspecific\S*id\b"** which will match anything that starts with specific and ends with id.
But, I want something which should match

`"specific-anything-id"`(it should be with double quotes)

`**<specific-anything-id>**` - should not match
`specific-"anything"-id` - should not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the double quotes and use a negated character class `[^"]`  (matching any char but `"`) rather than `\S` (that can also match double quotes as it matches any non-whitespace character):

```
var pattern = @"""specific[^""]*id""";
```

You do not need word boundaries either here.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22specific%5B%5E%22%5D*id%22&i=%22specific-anything-id%22%0D%0A%3Cspecific-anything-id%3E%0D%0Aspecific-%22anything%22-id) and a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/S5eCMC):

```
var s = "\"specific-anything-id\"  <specific-anything-id> specific-\"anything\"-id";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"""specific[^""]*id""");
foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value); // => "specific-anything-id"
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since now you have the upvoting privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
"([^"]+)"
```

the matched group would contain the ID you want.